# What does c99.Game mean in this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

This is part of a html5 game tutorial. Could someone explain what c99.Game mean in this context?

```
var c99 = {};

c99.Game = (function(){
    function Count99Game() {
        console.log("Starting");
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("game-canvas");
        this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
        this.stage.update();
    }

    return Count99Game;
})();

window.onload = function(){
    var game = new c99.Game()
};
```

Comment: it declare as an object

Comment: it means the `Game` property of `c99`?

Comment: You should back off a bit in the tutorial if you cannot tell what `{}` does …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var c99 = {};
```

This sets up an empty object... in this context, a way to set up a namespace of sorts.

```
c99.Game = (function(){
```

This adds a function to the `Game` property of the `c99` object.  An equivalent way would be something like this:

```
var c99 = {
    Game: function () {
        /* etc */
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

first you create an empty object c99:

```
var c99 = {}
```

then you add a property to that object:

```
c99.Game = ...
```